# Numerical Method code for non linear functions

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Respected all,
I am trying to find solution of 3 non linear equations using Newton Raphson Method in Matlab.Below is my code and I want this code to converge to a point (4,3,2).

Can some one please see my code.Thanks.

```
syms x y z
clc
xi=5;
yi=0;
zi=0;

xj=-5;
yj=0;
zj=0;

xk=0;
yk=0;
zk=5;

rij=-6.0537;
rik=3.8563;
rkj=2.1893;

k1=(xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2+(x-xj)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2-rij^2-2*((((x-xi)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2))*(x-xj)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2)^(1/2);

k2=(xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2+(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2-rik^2-2*((((x-xi)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2))*(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2)^(1/2);

k3=(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2+(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2-rkj^2-2*((((x-xk)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2))*(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2)^(1/2);

y1=diff(k1,x);
y2=diff(k1,y);
y3=diff(k1,z);
y4=diff(k2,x);
y5=diff(k2,y);
y6=diff(k2,z);
y7=diff(k3,x);
y8=diff(k3,y);
y9=diff(k3,z);

%% x=4 y=3 z=2
r1=3.5;
r2=2.5;
r3=1.9;

x=r1;
y=r2;
z=r3;
i=1;
x_s=r1;
y_s=r2;
z_s=r3;

while i<=200 

k0=[x y z]';%% Initial guess

rij=9.6953;
rik=3.8563;
rkj=2.1893;

k1=(xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2+(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2-(rij^2)-2*((((xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2))*(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2)^(1/2);

k2=(xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2+(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2-(rik^2)-2*((((xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2))*(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2)^(1/2);

k3=(xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2+(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2-(rkj^2)-2*((((xk-x)^2+(yk-y)^2+(zk-z)^2))*(xj-x)^2+(yj-y)^2+(zj-z)^2)^(1/2);

k=[k1 k2 k3]';


j=[y1 y2 y3;y4 y5 y6;y7 y8 y9];

syms x y z
A3 = subs(j, {x, y, z}, {x_s, y_s, z_s});

inverse_j=inv(A3);

l= k0-(inverse_j)*k;

x=l(1);
y=l(2);
z=l(3);
i=i+1;
k0=[x y z]';
x_s=l(1);
y_s=l(2);
z_s=l(3);

k0

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. The manner ,in which you have posted the problem, is illegible. You first go through [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use the methods while posting anything here.

Comment: Please, add at least the equations you're solving. For me the expression
`(((xi-x)^2+(yi-y)^2+(zi-z)^2))` seems erroneous since the second pair of parentheses is redundant. And it is multiplied by `(x-xi)` only. I assume that the original equation was
$$
k_1 = (\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r)^2 + (\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r)^2 - 2 |\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r| |\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r| - R_{ij}^2 = (|\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r| - |\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r|)^2 - R_{ij}^2
$$

Comment: Dear Thanks for your reply i will explain now.

Comment: No.The equation i wrote is right.Actually the equation is in 3-D .I have 3 receivers i,j and k each having 3-D Position e.g (5,0,0) .Have found distances between (x,y,z) and 3 receivers and then took the differences of these distances and got these equations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29272/discussion-on-question-by-jamil-hayder-numerical-method-code-for-non-linear-func).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original system of equations you're trying to solve is 
$$
(\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r)^2 + (\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r)^2 - 2 \sqrt{(\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r)^2 (\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r)^2} = r_{ij}^2\\
(\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r)^2 + (\mathbf r_k - \mathbf r)^2 - 2 \sqrt{(\mathbf r_i - \mathbf r)^2 (\mathbf r_k - \mathbf r)^2} = r_{ik}^2\\
(\mathbf r_k - \mathbf r)^2 + (\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r)^2 - 2 \sqrt{(\mathbf r_k - \mathbf r)^2 (\mathbf r_j - \mathbf r)^2} = r_{kj}^2
$$
which is simply squares of 
$$
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_j| = r_{ij}\\
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_k| = r_{ik}\\
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_k| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_j| = r_{kj}.
$$
It is easy to see that this problem has solutions only if $r_{ij} = r_{ik} + r_{kj}$, since the last two equations sum to the first one. Otherwise, there's no solutions. Moreover, when $r_{ij} = r_{ik} + r_{kj}$ there are infinitely many solutions.

[image]
[image]

To break the linear dependence one may add one more equation and remove the redundant one
$$
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_j| = r_{ij}\\
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_k| = r_{ik}\\
|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_l| = r_{il}.
$$

Denoting $\mathbf r_0 = \mathbf r_i, \mathbf r_1 = \mathbf r_j, \mathbf r_2 = \mathbf r_k, \mathbf r_3 = \mathbf r_l$,
$$
F_i = |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0| - |\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i| - r_{0i}
$$
The derivative $\frac{\partial \mathbf F}{\partial \mathbf r}$ can be easily computed by hand:
$$
\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial \mathbf r} = \frac{\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|} - \frac{\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_i|}.
$$
Now the Newton's method looks like
$$
\mathbf r^{(s+1)} = \mathbf r^{(s)} - \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_0^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|} - \frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_1^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_1|}\\
\frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_0^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|} - \frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_2^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_2|}\\
\frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_0^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0|} - \frac{\mathbf (\mathbf r^{(s)})^\top - \mathbf r_3^\top}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_3|}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
|\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_0| - |\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_1| - r_{01}\\
|\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_0| - |\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_2| - r_{02}\\
|\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_0| - |\mathbf r^{(s)} - \mathbf r_3| - r_{03}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I think the initial approximation
$$
\mathbf r^{(0)} = \frac{\mathbf r_0 + \mathbf r_1 + \mathbf r_2 + \mathbf r_3}{4}
$$
may work just well.

Here's a Matlab implementaion

```
r0 = [5; 0; 0];
r1 = [-5; 0; 0];
r2 = [0; 0; 5];
r3 = [0; 5; 0];

r01 = -3;
r02 = 3;
r03 = -2;

rs = 0.25 * (r0 + r1 + r2 + r3);

for it = 1:20
    F = [ norm(rs - r0) - norm(rs - r1) - r01; ...
          norm(rs - r0) - norm(rs - r2) - r02; ...
          norm(rs - r0) - norm(rs - r3) - r03 ];
    dFdr = [ (rs' - r0') / norm(rs - r0) - (rs' - r1') / norm(rs - r1); ...
             (rs' - r0') / norm(rs - r0) - (rs' - r2') / norm(rs - r2); ...
             (rs' - r0') / norm(rs - r0) - (rs' - r3') / norm(rs - r3) ];
    drs = dFdr \ F;
    rs = rs - drs;
    fprintf('||F|| = %e, ||drs|| = %e\n', norm(F), norm(drs));
    if norm(drs) < 1e-14
        break;
    end
end

rs
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for such a good explanation and also Matlab code.But when I run this code the output is far from initial guess.

Comment: I think it should be close to our initial guess,right

Comment: I wonder how you even bother to give such detailed answers to such poorly formulated questions

Comment: @uranix I really appreciate your efforts in giving such a detailed and comprehensive answer.But your code still does not converge to your initial guess.Kindly Please can you comment on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: @JamilHayder What parameters are you using? May be the problem has no solution.

Comment: @ValerySaharov If you understand the problem can you add some thing to it.As I am still trying to converge the solution close to initial guess.Please.I would appreciate your time.thanks ,regards

Comment: @uranix I am using the same parameters which you have assumed in your code but still not getting the converge answer.

Comment: @uranix kindly can you have a look on ur code which you wrote above please.I think may be u made some mistake while doing assumptions.As the solution is bit far from the guess please

Comment: I am really stuck in this.

Comment: @JamilHayder and why should the soluition be close to the guess? The only thing that matters is how well does the solution fit into the equations, provided that the solution is sane. The inverse should be true: if you take the initail guess close to the solution, the method should converge to that solution

Comment: @uranix well i agree your point .So adding to your point ,how I can guess a value which is close to the solution.I mean if i change some parameters then I need to guess again .So how I should I guess the initial values please.

Comment: It seems that the midpoint works as the initial guess well for every problem I've tested. The method diverged when the problem had no solution at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29352/discussion-between-jamil-hayder-and-uranix).

Comment: @uranix, I am sorry to interrupt you.Kindly can you read my message in chat please.Would be so nice of you.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @uranix I am sorry to bother you ,Kindly can you please comment on my last message in chat .Many thanks!

Comment: @uranix.It would be so nice if you respond to my comment in chat please.Thanks in advance!

Comment: @uranix.Kindly I request you please can you comment on my last message in chat.Thanks in advance please.

Comment: @uranix, Kindly I have a small question but I can not write it in the chat box it seems frozen.